# How to get the ID and not the Generated Key from Firebase Realtime Database in React?

Tags: reactjs, firebase-realtime-database, axios, xmlhttprequest

I was able to send a delete HTTP request to Firebase Realtime database and it gave me a status 200, but when I checked the database, it's not deleted. I console logged the id it's getting from the console and it gave me the right id. I think it's looking for the key and not the id. Is there a way to get the id itself and not the auto-generated key given by Firebase? Thanks in advance!

Here's the response log:

[image]

Here's my database structure wherein I would like to get the id:

[image]

Here's my code for deleting user:

```
  const deleteUser = (id) => {
    httpCommon.delete(`/users/${id}.json`).then((response) => {
      setEditing(false);
      setUsers(users.filter((user) => user.id !== id));
      console.log(response);
    });
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am correct you are trying to delete the document. So according to firebase documentation you need to do the following.

```
const res = await db.collection('cities').doc('DC').delete();
```